# Is the setup time a concern in asynchronous signals in processes?

Tags: vhdl, xilinx

When a signal is included in the sensitivity list, that process is executed every time that signal changes. For example,

```
-- State Memory
-- Synchronous Reset
process (clk)
begin
    if (rst = '1') then
        p_state <= initialization;
    elsif (rising_edge(clk)) then
        p_state <= n_state;
    end if;
end process;
```

However, if rst is included in the sensitivity list, it becomes asynchronous reset. My question now then would be, when rst is asserted. The process is executed. But is the rst signal stable already such that the value of the rst signal is '1'?

Comment: Can you please review and clarify you question; I cant figure out precisely what you are asking.  Bts. the code above will give you a synthesis warning about signals `rst` and `initialization` missing in the sensitivity list.

Answer (score 2):

Your example is not a synchronous reset.

It is an invalid implementation of an asynchronous reset, since `rst` is missing in the processes sensitivity list. In simulation it may look like a synchronous reset, but synthesis ignores the sensitivity list and synthesizes an asynchronous reset.

I assume `initialization` is a defined state and not a signal, otherwise you have another problem there (reset values should always be constant, and not dependent on another signal).

Answer (score 0):

Normally, VHDL is used to describe designs at the [register transfer level](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register-transfer_level). At this level of abstraction, setup and hold times are ignored. Since meeting setup and hold times is often more a function of the physical layout of the design, rather than the logic, this assumption is generally reasonable when verifying design logic.

When you write VHDL `process` blocks that have incomplete sensitivity lists, you risk differences between simulation and synthesis, since synthesis tools typically ignore sensitivity lists. As a result, you really have two choices:

```
-- Asynchronous Reset
process (clk, rst)
begin
    if (rst = '1') then
        p_state <= (others => '0');
    elsif (rising_edge(clk)) then
        p_state <= n_state;
    end if;
end process;

-- Synchronous Reset
process (clk)
begin
    if (rising_edge(clk)) then
        if (rst = '1') then
            p_state <= (others => '0');
        else
            p_state <= n_state;
        end if;
    end if;
end process;
```

You should not be implementing a synchronous reset by using the asynchronous reset pattern and then omitting `rst` from the sensitivity list.

Comment: The example with "Asynchronous Reset" above is missing `initialization` in the sensitivity list.  Also, having a value for asynchronous reset that depends on an external signal is likely to give problems in some FPGA technologies.

Comment: @MortenZdk Good catch... I didn't notice that the reset wasn't using a constant value.

Comment: @MortenZdk I assume that `initialization` is not a signal, but the state to start in after reset.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question properly, you are concerned about the **setup time** (and, consequently, also the **hold time**) of the flip-flop. Such times refer to the data input, not to the reset input, being required to prevent metastability and to achieve correct data storage.

An assynchronous reset forces the output to zero regardless of any other signal, overriding, at the flip-flop's transistor level, any data or clock related information.